# Trouble with event.stopPropagation() and onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I wrote this piece of code several years ago, and at the time, it works in Firefox and Chrome, but now, it results in an infinite loop in Chrome:

```
<script>
    function clickChildLink(el, event) {
        console.log('inside function');
        var evtTarget = $(event.target);
        if (evtTarget.is('a')) {
            console.log('returning');
            return; //ignore clicks if its a link
        }
        $(el).children('a').click();
}
</script>

<div onclick="clickChildLink(this, event);">  
    <a href="#" onclick="console.log('before'); event.stopPropagation(); console.log('after'); return false;">Header</a>
</div>
```

You can run the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Py7Mu/205/

Basically, what its supposed to do, is if the user clicks inside the div (i.e. Header), it finds the link within it, and invokes a click on it. On Chrome, that invoked click also propagates back to the parent, which in turn starts the whole process again.

I know I should be using less obtrusive JavaScript, but this stems from an old rails app (upgrade will hopefully come soon enough).

Any idea why the event doesn't actually stop propagating? Technically, the code should work without the `stopPropagation` call, as the if statement inside the function should stop subsequent calls from firing. Apparently, Chrome does not update the `currentTarget` when programmatically invoking a click.

Comment: Well, there is one thing I can see: Firefox sees the event as belonging to the `a` element, when Chrome believe's it belongs to the `div`.

Comment: Here is the same code showing the `event` in the console; I also stop the loop to save on sanity `;)`. http://jsfiddle.net/Py7Mu/213/

Comment: Thanks Jared...In hindsight, I see how the code could be a little annoying to watch. I'm not sure why Chrome doesn't update the target when you programmatically invoke the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is only one child anchor could you not just do something like...

```
$(el).click(function(){
    if (this.tagName !== 'A') 
        this.getElementsByTagName('A')[0].click();
});
```

or i guess if it's nested further down...

```
$(el).click(function(){
    if (this.tagName !== 'A') 
        $('a', this)[0].click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks...this ended up working... weirdly enough, the currentTarget in the event is correctly updated using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is caused by the event handlers being attached inline. If you attach them using jQuery, onDomReady, it should work, and better yet, cross-browser (your current script won't work in IE <9). Also, you don't need the anchor check inside your event handler if you can properly stop the propagation.

Try this:

```
$(function(){

    $(div).click(function(){
        $(this).children('a').click();
    });

    $(a).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```